# Checkbox item adds to spinner

Tags: java, android, checkbox, spinner

i have two checkbox and when a checkbox item is selected it should be added to spinner. is it possible to do that? cant find it on google, so hoping somebody can save me here :) 
my spinner :

```
public class Checkbox extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkbox);

    Spinner spinner;
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.itinerary, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

the layout

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cbSiargao"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Surigao"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="104dp" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/cbSiargao"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="139dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="139dp" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Boracay"
    android:id="@+id/checkBox"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cbSiargao"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Comment: put your spinner adapter

Comment: adding spinner adapter done. what's next? how can i add selected checkbox to my spinner?

Comment: what? where? i cannot see the adapter code

Comment: there. should i really be adding this "R.array.itinerary" since the items that i want to be view on my spinner are the items that are checked on my checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-implement your spinner adapter. Here's a quick example:

```
public class SpinnerAdapterExample implements SpinnerAdapter {
    public ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View parent, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(parent.getContext());
    textView.setText(items.get(position));
    return textView;
}
```

Don't forget to re-implement the other required methods, but you could leave them as is.

In your checkbox class add the follow:

```
SpinnerAdapterExample adapter = new SpinnerAdapterExample();
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then whenever you need to add something to spinner write the following code:

```
adapter.items.add("new item");
spinner.notifyOnDatasetChanged();
```

Comment: so there will be two classes? uhm.. where will i place this adapter.items.add("new item");
spinner.notifyOnDatasetChanged(); ?

Comment: Those two lines should be added every time you want to an item to the spinner. Of course you will have to change "new item" the item you actually want to add.